# Can you change Drawer Item style without making custom drawer in react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, navigation-drawer

I'm using Drawer Navigator in my react-native App and I am wondering if you can change the style of the item present in Drawer screen without making cusom drawer ? Something like providing custom view style to Drawer.Screen, so it's not so basic like addding an Icon before the text

[image: My drawer]

[image: My drawer screen component]

Like adding some prop to `<Drawer.Screen>`

Answer (score 0):

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/

If props `style` and `labelStyle` are good for you?

Comment: but wouldn't it require me making a custom drawer ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Look at these options of the Drawer Navigator please: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#draweritemstyle

All of them are about of the styles of default Component

Answer (score 0):

You can pass these props to Drawer.Screen to personalize however you want.

For Example:

```
  <Draw.Screen
        name={screens.PROFILE}
        component={Profile}
        options={{
          headerTitleStyle: {fontFamily: 'Gugi-Regular'},
          drawerLabel: navLabels.PROFILE,
          drawerIcon: () => (
            <View style={styles.drawIconStyles}>
              <Icon name={icons.PERSON_ICON} size={25} tint={'#9E9E9E'} />
            </View>
          ),
          drawerItemStyle: {backgroundColor: 'red'},
        }}
      />
```

[image]